# yarn monorepo with multiple versioning files, fix yarn version check or reset

Tags: next.js, versioning, monorepo, yarn-workspaces

Given the following state of my NextJS monorepo app:

- monorepo with multiple private packages managed via yarn workspaces
- `develop` is default branch, testing environment and has multiple commits ahead of `main`
- `main` branch has fewer commits and only those ready for staging environment
- commits to `main` are pushed via PRs with cherry-picking from `develop`
- `develop` versioning of those private monorepo packages is all green (the `yarn version check` command)
- version checking is disabled PR-level and branch level on `main` and due to cherry-picking/reverts/squash/etc. the `yarn version check` fails on the `main` branch with the following error:

```bash
yarn version check
➤ YN0001: UsageError: Your current branch contains multiple versioning files; this isn't supported:
- /Users/tbutcaru/Projects/my-nextjs-app/.yarn/versions/00648a82.yml
- /Users/tbutcaru/Projects/my-nextjs-app/.yarn/versions/009a6542.yml
- /Users/tbutcaru/Projects/my-nextjs-app/.yarn/versions/018f7b67.yml
- /Users/tbutcaru/Projects/my-nextjs-app/.yarn/versions/0197a805.yml
    at h (/Users/tbutcaru/Projects/my-nextjs-app/.yarn/plugins/@yarnpkg/plugin-version.cjs:5:3539)
    at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
....
```

- the mentioned `.yarn/versions/...` files do not exist in my `main` branch.

Same issue [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/2783) and [here](https://github.com/yarnpkg/berry/issues/4510) - closed without solution. I've already tried what others have said through comments in the mentioned links.

**I've tried:**

- `yarn version apply --all`
- `yarn version check --interactive`
- upgrade to latest yarn 3.4.0 (using 2.4.2 right now)
- deleted all `.yarn/versions` file dir + yarn.lock and reinstall all packages
- manually bump all private packages versions
- copy the `.yarn/versions` file dir from `develop` to `main`
- added `changesetIgnorePatterns: - '.yarn/**/*'` in the `.yarnrc.yml` file and I no longer get the error above but the following `YN0000: @my-nextjs-app/shared-components@workspace:packages/shared-components has been modified but doesn't have a release strategy attached` and I've run the `yarn version check --interactive`, so the package has a release strategy attached, but still the `yarn version check` fails.

... none of the above worked.

How can I fix the "multiple versioning files" issue?
Or, at least, how do I completely reset/reinit the yarn workspace packages versions on the `main` branch?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't find any solution to my issue with the initial setup described in the original post, but I've manage to fix the `yarn version check --interactive` with a `.yarnrc.yml` config change!

I'll try to provide a bit more context on the issue and solution.

Recently I've changed my repo's default branch from `develop` to `main` and that's how I've ended up with the issue above. The idea behind the default branch switch was to move to `main` and archive `develop` forever and that created a task of removing all codebase and configs related to `develop`.

So, while working on removing any `develop` branch leftovers from my repo, I've reached to `.yarnrc.yml` which had the following config:

```yaml
changesetBaseRefs:
  - develop
  - origin/develop
  - upstream/develop
```

... changing it to:

```yaml
changesetBaseRefs:
  - main
  - origin/main
  - upstream/main
```

... resulted in `yarn version check --interactive` and `yarn version check` to work!